# Find the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{x-1})^2$

Tags: derivatives

In this case $n=16$ and the point is $x=1$.

I know $\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable in zero, but this function actually has left derivatives.

Also, I know that $f(x)=(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{x-1})^2=x^2+x-2+2\sqrt{(x^2-1)(x-1)}$, so it is enogth to compute the derivative of $2\sqrt{(x^2-1)(x-1)}$.

Also, I tried to find the $n$th derivative of $\sqrt{g(x)}$ but its expresion was too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Since $x\ge 1$, we may write $\sqrt{(x^2-1)(x-1)}=(x-1)\sqrt{x+1}$.

Then, use the [General Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for product differentiation

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left((x-1)\sqrt{x+1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x-1)\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}(x+1)^{1/2}$$

Finish by recognizing that the only surviving terms occur at $k=0$ and $k=1$.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, not just $a$.

Comment: @Michaelhoppe Yes, I know that.  But the domain is $x\ge1$, so the absolute value is superfluous.  Do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

For convenience take $x = 1+t$, so $x=1$ corresponds to $t=0$.
Thus 
$$ \eqalign{f(x) &= \left(\sqrt{(1+t)^2-1} + \sqrt{t}\right)^2\cr
&= t^2 + 3t + 2 + 2 \sqrt{t^2+2t}\sqrt{t}\cr
&= t^2 + 3t + 2 + 2 t \sqrt{t+2}\cr
&= t^2 + 3t + 2 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{2} (-1)^k (2k)! t^{k+1}}{8^k (k!)^2 (1-2k)}
}$$
The $16$'th derivative at $t=0$ comes from the $k=15$ term:

$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{d^{16}}{dt^{16}} \dfrac{2\sqrt{2} (-1)^{15} 30! \; t^{16}}{8^{15} (15!)^2 (-29)} &= \dfrac{2\sqrt{2} (-1)^{15} 30! 16!}{8^{15} (15!)^2 (-29)} \cr &= \frac{213458046676875}{33554432} 
\sqrt{2}}$$